# How to maintain separate Calendar holiday schedule in Job Scheduling

Tags: java, spring-boot, scheduler, job-scheduling, java-calendar

I have a requirement, wherein there are multiple jobs which gets triggered on based on their nature, Monthly, Daily etc. Every job have different schedule, for example, if 3/31 is holiday for Job X, its a working day for Job Y. Similarly, schedules may for vary for calendar dates.

I want to keep separate Calendar configuration is Database, so that I have flexibility to customize holiday schedule, rather than having a one single generic calendar, and I don't have flexibility.

What would be best way to do it?

****Number of Jobs would be in thousands, so it wont be best to have separate calendar tables for each job.*****

Any suggestions/advice would be appreciated.

Comment: It’s very broad. Please don’t mistake Stack Overflow for a data modeling or design service.

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't restricted to RDBMS, you could create a table in a noSql database with a standard schedule and a collection of unique override events in which the standard schedule for the job would be overridden.

Of course this storage strategy presumes the fact that you already have a manner in which you can pull the schedules in a dynamic manner to determine which job runs at which time and on what day.